# A bounded function is integrable if and only if $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification

As the title states, I want to prove the following:

A bounded function $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ such that
$$U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon.$$

I have found other proofs of this online and in textbooks, but I wanted to see whether my method works.

Essentially, I attempt to prove this by assuming $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$ and then proving that $f$ is integrable using iff statements, proving both directions of implication at once.

This is the rough outline of my idea: I construct two sets $A$ and $B$ as follows:
$$A = \{ L(f,P) \;|\; \text{P is a partition of } [a,b] \}$$
$$B = \{ U(f,Q) \;|\; \text{Q is a partition of } [a,b] \}$$

Now we know that $L(f,P) \leq U(f,Q) \iff A \leq B \iff \sup(A) \leq \inf(B)$. Using our assumption that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$, we know that $\sup(A) = \inf(B)$. (I have already proved this result; namely, $\sup(A) = \inf(B) \iff \exists a \in A, b \in B$ such that $a - b < \epsilon$.)

Now $\sup(A) = \inf(B) \iff f$ is integrable.

Please let me know if there are any errors you can spot! Thanks.

Comment: This is the way the proof is done. Your proof is same as the standard proof presented in many textbooks. Only thing to notice is that the proof shows the existence of two partitions $P1, P2$ such that $U(f, P1) - L(f, P2) <\epsilon$. The result is now obtained by taking $P=P1\cup P2$.